# Request::is() only work on parent route. How to use that on child route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I've tried using `Request::is()` to print some bootstrap class but unfortunately, it only works on the parent route `user`, but when I use it in their child, it is not working on `user/create`

Here is my code:

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li class="{{ Request::is('posts') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a class="nav-link" href="/posts">Posts</a></li>
     <li class="{{ Request::is('posts/create') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a class="nav-link" href="/posts/create">Create New</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, can you specify more about `not working` written

Comment: when URL is 'posts/create'  the class is not active yet so i think the problem is with my code "Request::is()" @bhucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `(*)` for any route before or after the URL:

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
     //post/sub_url
     <li class="{{ Request::is('posts/*') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a class="nav-link" href="/posts">Posts</a></li>
     //match url
     <li class="{{ Request::is('posts/create') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a class="nav-link" href="/posts/create">Create New</a></li>
     //match any sub_url with any prefix
     <li class="{{ Request::is('*/posts/create/*') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a class="nav-link" href="/posts/create">Create New</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `Request::segment(1)` for parent because for child also  `segment(1)` will be `post` or i prefer to put in  `in_array()` so need i can add more route to parent `active`

```php
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="{{ in_array(Request::segment(1),['post']) ? 'active' : '' }}"><a class="nav-link" href="/posts">Posts</a></li>
    <li class="{{ in_array(Request::segment(1),['post']) ? 'active' : '' }}"><a class="nav-link" href="/posts/create">Create New</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: only work on the parent route, the child still doesn't change to active yet

Comment: @CaturBagas try now